Drag and drop is broken on 24.10 upgrade
I've just upgraded from 24.04 to 24.10 and found that drag and drop via the launchbar no longer seems to work.
What used to happen (24.04):
open 20 instances of firefox (don't ask) and 1 of libre office Calc...
within each instance of firefox are multiple tabs.
To sort some of the tabs I might drag one tab down to the launchbar and over one of the instances of firefox.
A matrix of open applications pops up (like when you press the 'Super' button on the keyboard).
I then drag the tab over to one of the open apps and the tab is added to that application.

Now (24.10)..
I drag the tab down and onto an existing instance on the launchbar and at best it turns the tab into a new firefox instance.
I haven't changed any apps or plugins. Although extension manager tells me that applications menus, dash to panel & user themes were upgraded.
DiNG is also enabled, although turning that off doesn't seem to help.
I can still get by if I tap the left 'Super' key while doing the dragging, but it used to be automatic... has a setting been changed? (got 7 pc's to fix if this is the case).
Does anyone know how to return the functionality to the way it was, or is this a gnome change?

bug lodged on launchpad
